# Retrieve input from db with php and have different css class

Tags: php, css, arrays, database

I have a site who are gonna show which games are running. They are in a *table* and each game have a *th*. I wants to make them different from each other. Ex if the game are HS U11A then it should be *th class=blue*

Current script:

```
$sql = "SELECT kamp, kategori, raekke, tid, loebenr FROM turneringsinfo WHERE loebenr LIKE '1' ORDER BY loebenr ASC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "<table>";
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<th>" . $row["kategori"]. ' ' . $row["raekke"]. "</th>";
     }
     echo "</table>";
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}
```

Outputs:

```
<table>
<th>HS U11 A</th>
<th>DS U13 B</th>
<th>HS U17 A</th>
<th>HS SEN A</th>
<th>HS SEN D</th>
<th>HS U11 B</th>
<th>HS U19 A</th>
```

Wanted output:

```
<table>
<th class="red">HS U11 A</th>
<th class="green">DS U13 B</th>
<th class="blue">HS U17 A</th>
<th>HS SEN A</th>
<th>HS SEN D</th>
<th>HS U11 B</th>
<th>HS U19 A</th>
```

What I've found that I think could give help me in this case

```
$setning  = "You should eat fruits, vegetables, and fiber every day.";
$gammeltord = array("fruits", "vegetables", "fiber");
$nyttord   = array("pizza", "beer", "ice cream");
$nysetning = str_replace($gammeltord, $nyttord, $setning);


echo "$nysetning"
```

The site is also live so you can see the visuals here: http://turneringsportalen.no/beta/tidslinje.php

Hope i have explained myself and are looking forward for your help :)

Regards Øystein

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how these game names are generated, or perhaps they are static strings but since you specifically ask to tag those values:

```
$tags = [
  'HS U11 A' => 'red',
  'DS U13 B' => 'green',
  'HS U17 A' => 'blue'
];

$sql = "SELECT kamp, kategori, raekke, tid, loebenr FROM turneringsinfo WHERE loebenr LIKE '1' ORDER BY loebenr ASC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  echo "<table>";
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if(array_key_exists(($name = $row["kategori"]. ' ' . $row["raekke"]), $tags)){
      echo "<th class='".$tags[$name]."'>" . $name. "</th>";
    } else {
      echo "<th>" . $name. "</th>";
    }
  }
  echo "</table>";
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
```

This works by checking if the key of array `$tags` exists (setting a new var `$name` with those values) and print out if it exists.

Comment: Is it a missing { or } somewhere in your code? Just getting error and a page that looks like this: http://turneringsportalen.no/beta/uttest.php

Comment: Thx for the answer. Worked like a charm! :)

Comment: I know, I noticed the updates on your live page, also noticicing you should use `<td>` where `td` stands for `table data` and `<th>` stands for `table header`. Doing this, would align your table. Also, it would be appreciated to up-vote as well.

Comment: Thx again. Has updatet it again wit <tr> correct td and correct th :) Thx!

Comment: You've updated already! To keep up to date, header information belongs into `<thead>`, body information to `<tbody>` and optionally put footer info into `<tfoot>`. Either way your table is mature enough for today's standard.

Comment: Ok! :) Added the thead and tbody now ;)

Comment: Sorry about all this, th is table header and it belongs in <thead>. tr or td (table row\data)can belong in <tbody>. My mistake.